# Exact one word for "Eligible for modification in future"

Tags: single-word-requests

I was writing a kind-of technical document for commercial company.

The product/item which we are writing about may or may not undergo some changes and we needed to document this point clearly in our product documentation.

So, I am looking for What exactly is the correct word for

> The product may or may not be modified in future

Comment: What's wrong with modifiable? Also see pliable or pliant and malleable.

Comment: Personally I like the way it sounds currently.

Comment: When writing documentation, the aim is not to use as few words as possible: the aim is to communicate as clearly as possible.  Use more words if it's clearer.

Comment: If you're looking to pare superfluous verbiage, start by writing "This item" for *The product/item which we are writing about*.

Comment: Is it a temporary/placeholder value before you get the final version, in which case it's "contingent" (or similar terms), or is it something that's correct now but may be changed (like who's president), or something that's continually changing (like an exchange rate)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say that it is "subject to modification" or "subject to change".  This conveys the idea that not only is it *possible* for it to change, it's actually *likely*.

Comment: That's "exact one word?"

Comment: @Kris obviously not.  But, as I pointed out to the poster in a comment on the question, sometimes it's better to use more words to get a point across more clearly.  My guess was that the poster didn't actually **need** the answer to be a single word, even though that was in the question title.

Answer (score 2):

Try [alterable](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/alterable)

> Able to be changed. To make different without changing into something else or **modify**

Answer (score 2):

"Updatable" is quite used in the IT world.

Answer (score 2):

Mutable means

> capable of change or of being changed

[M-W](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/mutable)